# Protect apache pages by URL

Tags: apache-2.2

Is it possible to allow access to specific URLs only to certain networks?
Basically, I would like to restrict access to the admin area only to the local network
This area's pages are prefixed by /admin
Essentially, I would like all /admin/* to be forbidden from public access.

Can apache handle such a case?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Using your suggestions I came up to

```
 <LocationMatch admin>
    Order allow,deny
    deny from all
    Allow From 192.168.11.0/255.255.255.0
  </LocationMatch>
```

However, I get 403 even though I am on the network.

Additionally, if I put apache behind haproxy, is this going to work? Because the traffic will be coming from 127.0.0.1 to apache

**UPDATE 1**

Correct directive is as follows

```
    <LocationMatch admin>
        Order deny,allow
        deny from all
        Allow From 192.168.11
      </LocationMatch>
```

However, the problem with the proxy in front of apache is not handled by the above
Is there any way to overcome it?

Comment: As documented, the above is not valid. Use ip.pre.fix instead. You also don't need to use LocationMatch here.

Comment: Feeling a bit stupid here. Based on the docs this is valid notation. What do you mean by ip prefix?

Comment: Oh, it is valid. just use `192.168.11.0/24` then. But that is identical to `192.168.11`

Comment: Tried with 192.168.11 as well, but with no luck

Answer (score 1):

As documented in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html, this is trivially done inside a Directory container as follows:

```
<Directory /your/document/root/admin>
  Order allow,deny
  allow from your.internal.network
  deny from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: The problem is that there is no admin directory. All urls are handled by the MVC framework with a front controller.

Comment: Try `<Location>` instead? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location

Comment: Please check my updated question